# how to telnet expect ascii character cli - python 2.7

Tags: python, ascii, expect, telnetlib

python telnet conn

send {msg},

recv msg log,

```
1 : ^[]0;ABCD - ABCD - file=/tmp/1234^GConnected to 123.123.123.123 (test=test_ROOT_MO,Context=ABCD,ManagedElement=ABCD)^M
2 : ^M
3 : Last MO: 11668. Loaded 11668 . Total: 11669 MOs.^M
4 : ^M

5 : ^[[1;32mABCD^[[0m>
```

this msg(^[[1;32mABCD^[[0m>) in log
, but telnet conn, and send msg

```
    ABCD> msg
    ABCD - ABCD - file=/tmp/1234^GConnected to 123.123.123.123 (test=test_ROOT_MO,Context=ABCD,ManagedElement=ABCD)
    Last MO: 11668. Loaded 11668 . Total: 11669 MOs.   

    *ABCD>*
```

last ABCD> is colorfull(green)

Q). I want find " ^[[1;32mABCD^[[0m> " (ABCD is always change)

I try under code, but failed

--> self.teln.read_until('\^[.*\^[.*>.*',300)

Comment: Format your code and your answer in general properly, please. Check [ask]

Answer (score 0):

With the Tcl expect I would advise:

> I assume you're trying to match the prompt, and the colour codes are messing you up. I'd keep it as simple as possible: match the angle bracket and space at the end of input:
>   `expect -re {> $}`

With python's [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html), it appears that `read_until` does not work with a regular expression. I wonder if this will be sufficient:

```
self.teln.read_until('[0m> ', 300)
```

Perhaps you want `read_eager()` or `read_very_eager()` instead.